# Every Linear Functional is zero or surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the Following Proof Correct ?

**Theorem.**  Given that $\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbf{F})$ represent the set of all linear functionals from the finite dimensional vector space $V$ to the scalar field $\mathbf{F}$, every member  of $\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbf{F})$ is either surjective or Zero.

**Proof.** Let $\phi\in \mathcal{L}(V,\mathbf{F})$ and $c\in\mathbf{F}$ assume that $\phi\neq 0$. We may assume without loss of generality that 
$$\phi = A_1\phi_1+A_2\phi_2+.\ .\ .\ A_m\phi_m$$ where $A_1,A_2,...A_m\in\mathbf{F}$ and that $\phi_1,\phi_2,...,\phi_m$ is the basis of the dual of $V$ which has the basis $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ furthermore since $\phi\neq 0$ it follows that the set $\alpha$
$$\alpha = \{A\in\{A_1,A_2,...,A_m\}\big|A\neq 0\} = \{B_1,B_2,...,B_{|\alpha|}\}$$
is such that $\alpha\neq\varnothing$, where $|\alpha|\leq \dim V.$

Now let $$c=\sum_{j=1}^{|\alpha|}C_j$$ where $C_j\in\mathbf{F}$ and consider the vector $v\in V$ such that 
$$v = \sum_{j=1}^{|\alpha|}\frac{C_j}{B_j}v_j$$
where $v_j$ and therefore $\phi_j$ corresponds to $B_j$ applying $\phi$ to $v$ yields
$$\phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^{|\alpha|}\frac{C_j}{B_j}v_j\right) = c$$

since $c$ was arbitrary it follows that $\phi$ is indeed surjective

$\blacksquare$

Comment: I think a simpler way to solve this would be to note that the range of a linear functional is a subspace of $F$, so it only has 2 possible dimensions.

Comment: There's actually a really simple proof: if $\phi \in \mathcal{L}(V, \mathbf{F})$, and $\phi \neq 0$, then there exists some $v \in V$ such that $\phi(v) = a \neq 0$. Then $\phi(\frac{1}{a}v) = 1$, so let's name $w = \frac{1}{a}v$. Now, if $x \in \mathbf{F} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is arbitrary, $\phi(xw) = x\phi(w) = x$, and if $x = 0$, then $\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: @MatthewPereira You Thug Lifed my Proof